# Using ES6 and Node.js, recommended way to require

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Using ES6, and Node.js, what is the recommend way to require packages `let` or `const`?

```
let _ = require('underscore');
```

or

```
const _ = require('underscore');
```

Comment: `const` because you want to reserve that variable

Comment: It's been answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483926/const-vs-var-while-requiring-a-module

Comment: The official docs use `const foo = require('foo')`: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you plan on ever redefining the package within the scope of your file (or wherever you're `require`ing) then it's probably best to use `const`: This will protect against accidental reassignments of the package variable.

For instance:

```
const _ = require('underscore');
// ...
let [a, _] = foo;  // SyntaxError: "_" is read-only
```

Since we're talking about ES6, `const`, and `require`, it makes sense to bring up `import` statements as well, which for the most part can be thought of as a more flexible version of `require`. [1]

```
import _ from 'underscore';
// ...
let [a, _] = foo;  // TypeError: duplicate declaration "_"
```

ES6 `import`s register as `const` by default, thus similarly preventing reassignment.

So, when would you want to use `let` for a require? Let's say (no pun intended) you want to use a special version of a package in certain environments.

```
let secureLibrary = require('secureLibrary');
// override all security in dev mode
if (process.env['NODE_ENV'] === 'development') {
    secureLibrary = secureLibrary.fake;
}
```

In this contrived example, during development, your use of secureLibrary will be replaced by a fake one, presumably ignoring self-signed SSL certificates or some other convenience that would be unsuitable for production.

In summary: most of the time use `const` but occasionally `let` provides necessary flexibility, and consider using `import` if you're already using ES6!

[1] **Please note:** under the hood there are many more differences between ES6 `import` and CommonJS `require`, please see [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export) and http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html for many more gory details.

Comment: For underscore it should be `import * as _ from 'underscore'`