# JavaScript - Owner of "this"

Tags: javascript, class, methods, this, console.log

I followed a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29330/JavaScript-Stopwatch) for creating a JavaScript stopwatch and am trying to expand it to work with multiple stopwatches (multiple instances of a class).  The problem I have is when I am trying to display the current value while the clock is ticking I need to hard code the class instance becasue using "this" doesn't work (on the line where I am using console.log).  I have cut the code down to the minimum to try to understand this aspect, and have pasted what I have below:

```
function Timer(){
    var time1 = null;
    var time2 = null;
    var timeLoop = null;

    function getTime(){
        var day = new Date();
        return day.getTime();
    }

    this.start = function(){
        time1 = getTime();

        timeLoop = setInterval(function(){
            time2 = getTime();
            console.log(_Timer.duration());
            //console.log(this.duration());
        },500);
    }

    this.duration = function(){
        return (time1 - time2) / 1000;
    }

}
```

I think the link below describes my problem but I don't understand it enough to apply it here.  Is the issue due to the owner being this.start rather than just this and how can I ammend the code to make it work with any instance of Timer?

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

I have included both the hard coded value line and the "this" line that doesn't work.

Thanks,

Geraint

Comment: copy "this" into "that". don't use "self" or other pre-defined variables names that complicate debugging.

Comment: @dandavis - Yes, that's why everyone uses `self`, plugins, jQuery, even Google, because it's bad. And when used outside the global scope it does not in any way conflict with `window.self`

Comment: just because something is common doesn't mean it can't be better. i see a ton of bad js all the time, and i wouldn't call using self "bad". in case of mis-execution, a ReferenceError is typically easier to find than a TypeError because it includes the name of the missing variable in the error message. why give closures an invisible failure path if there's something comparable that fails louder with no drawbacks?

Comment: i was big into webworkers before node, where self is like window, but "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet"...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to have the `this` property be consistent, you should bind the functions that are being called.

For example,

`setInterval(function() { /* code here */ }.bind(this), 500)`

That way, the `this` of the inner function will be the same as that of the outer function.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you see `function` you can assume the value of `this` changes, so inside the callback function for the interval `this` is actually the `window`, not the object.

The easy solution is to just store `this` in a variable

```
function Timer(){
    var time1 = null;
    var time2 = null;
    var timeLoop = null;

    function getTime(){
        var day = new Date();
        return day.getTime();
    }

    this.start = function(){

        var self = this;

        time1 = getTime();

        timeLoop = setInterval(function(){
            time2 = getTime();
            console.log(self.duration());
        },500);
    }

    this.duration = function(){
        return (time1 - time2) / 1000;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not a local variable, so it doesn't get saved in closures. You need to assign a local variable:

```
this.start = function(){
    var self = this;
    time1 = getTime();

    timeLoop = setInterval(function(){
        time2 = getTime();
        console.log(self.duration());
    },500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function Timer(){
    var time1 = null;
    var time2 = null;
    var timeLoop = null;
    var _this = this;

    function getTime(){
        var day = new Date();
        return day.getTime();
    }

    this.start = function(){
        time1 = getTime();

        timeLoop = setInterval(function(){
            time2 = getTime();
            console.log(_this.duration());
        },500);
    }

    this.duration = function(){
        return (time1 - time2) / 1000;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first. Javascript doesn't support class based OOP. It's OOP along with it's inheritance is prototypal.

Following is an example of how to implement prototypal OOP features with your timer example:

```
function Timer(){
  var time1 = null;
  var time2 = null;
  var timeLoop = null;
}

Timer.prototype.getTime = function(){
    var day = new Date();
    return day.getTime();
}

Timer.prototype.start = function(){
    time1 = this.getTime();
    timeLoop = this.setInterval(function(){
        time2 = this.getTime();
        console.log(this.duration());
    }.bind(this),500);
}

Timer.prototype.duration = function(){
    return (time1 - time2) / 1000;
}
```

Look at the Custom Objects section of [MDN's Javscript Reintroduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)

There's nothing wrong with the way it's shown in your tutorial. It's just that this is a cleaner way and the `bind` call is only needed for the `console.log` statement which would otherwise associate `this` as the `window`. If you get rid of it you can get rid of the `bind` too.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`bind(this)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24539568/4058484) works perfectly.

```js
var timer = {
  start: function() {
    setInterval(function() {console.log(this.duration());}.bind(this), 1000);
  }
}

timer.start();
```

But it can be unnecessary if you are using [`const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/const-in-javascript-when-to-use-it-and-is-it-necessary) with an arrow function:

```js
const timer = {
  start() {
    setInterval(() => {console.log(this.duration());}, 1000);
  }
}

timer.start();
```