# Function doesn't work - (this) changes it's value within it

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have this simple code that `toggle`s all elements of a class `thumbnail` except of the one clicked. Then after 2seconds a specific class should be added or removed to clicked element, depending on whether it's already selected.

The problem is with `setTimeout` (most likely) as it won't run my function, that checks via `if else` if clicked element should be selected or unselected, and then adds/remove `selected-ser` class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumbnail").click(function(){
        $('.thumbnail').not(this).toggle(2000);

        setTimeout(function() {             
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected-ser')) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected-ser');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('selected-ser');
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

I really tried to search for similar topics already solved, but I don't understand the way it doesn't work (It may be the function itself that's wrong, but I have no clue)

Thank you very much.

Edit: as it seems  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539521/javascript-owner-of-this)  topic adresses the same issue. I wasn't able to search for it before, as I didn't know the problem was with "owner of `this`". Thus I'm renaming this topic to "Function doesn't work - (this) changes it's value within it." So people dealing with same problem canbit more eaisly search for it, not knowing why doesn't the function work properly.

Thank you

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: please create a jsfiddle. The issue seems to be with this inside setTimeout

Comment: Inside setTimeout function callback, `this` refers to window object. So use a closure or set relevant context, e.g: `setTimeout(function() {/**/}.bind(this), 2000);`

Comment: A. Wolff ... Awesome! Your suggestion worked! I made var with $(this) outside of the function and then worked with that var. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a variable to reference `$(this)` then call it in inside of `setTimeout` it will do what you want. I added some css so you can see what's happening, but the example below will do what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    function changeClass() {
      $this.toggleClass('selected-ser');
    }
    $('.thumbnail').not(this).toggle(2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      changeClass();
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  border: solid;
}
.selected-ser {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumbnail").click(function(){
        $_this = $(this);
        $('.thumbnail').not(this).toggle(2000);

        setTimeout(function() {             
            if ($_this.hasClass('selected-ser')) {
                $_this.removeClass('selected-ser');
            } else {
                $_this.addClass('selected-ser');
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

You can't use `$(this)` to within another event/trigger to access element