# AJAX form sends information, PHP doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i had a issue with this exact form a fews days ago and was fixed with a different PHP thanks to you guys. Now i changed one thing in the form and it does not work anymore. I have alerted all the variables being sent through AJAX and they are correct values that i need. Here are the code for the HTML form:

```
 <?php
        include('php/connect.php');

        $chquery = "SELECT * FROM rooms";
        $chresult = mysqli_query($conn, $chquery);

        while($chrow = mysqli_fetch_array($chresult)){
            echo "<div class='edit_roomRow'>";
            echo "<h1> Rum " . $chrow['Roomnumber'] . "</h1>";
            echo "<form>";
            echo "Rumsnummer:<br> <input id='c-roomnumber' type='text' value = '" . $chrow['Roomnumber'] . "'><br>";
            echo "Beskrivning:<br> <input id='c-description' type='text' value = '" . $chrow['Description'] . "'>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "<br>";
            *update* echo "<div class='btn btn-warning change-btn' data-value='". $chrow['ID'] . "' style='float: right; margin-top: 100px;'>Ändra</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<hr/>";
        }

        mysqli_free_result($chresult);

        mysqli_close($conn);

 ?>
```

The AJAX is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".change-btn").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("data-value");
        var description = $("#c-description").val();
        var roomnumber = $("#c-roomnumber").val();
        //Call to ajax
        $.ajax({
            method:"GET",
            url: "php/changepost.php",
            data:{ id: id, description: description, roomnumber: roomnumber },
            success: function(){
                $("#c-description").val("");
                $("#c-roomnumber").val("");
                //Reload specific div with rooms, avoid full page reload
                $(".changerooms").load(location.href + " .changerooms");
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

I have tried changing around the variables, in the php etc.

```
<?php
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    include('connect.php');

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE rooms SET Roomnumber = ?, Description = ?, WHERE ID = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isi", $_GET['roomnumber'], $_GET['description'], $_GET['id']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

The DB is setup like this:

```
ID | Description | Roomnumber| Cleaned | Cleaner | Time
```

The last three are irrelevant here but figued i show the full db setup. I can add new posts etc. with the same values but when it comes to changing something isn't right with this code. Hope someone can help me with this :)

Comment: You know that the PHP script is expecting `$_GET['roomid']` but you're not sending that in the AJAX `data` parameter, right? You're only sending `id`, `description`, and `roomnumber`.

Comment: I'm sending roomnumber and the PHP is expecting $_GET['roomnumber'] as value for the column roomid in the database

Comment: What I mean is, look at the line `if(isset($_GET['roomid'])){`....

Comment: You know the PHP script never returns anything, and just times out.

Comment: Changed it to $_GET['id'] now, so it checks if the selected post has an ID. Still does not work

Comment: `id`'s MUST be unique in a page. Yours are not. So javascript does not know what to send to the PHP script

Comment: Look at the javascript debugger in your browser F12 you should see some sort of error message

Comment: @RiggsFolly Since the variables are sent through AJAX with the ID's a name is not needed. Putting names on there did not fix the issues.. :/

Comment: Yes but `var description =$("#c-description").val();` does not address JUST ONE ID..... hence nonsense rules

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hmm.. I guess that is the issue then, that it is only adressing one of all ID's. Any ideas how i can select once specific posts value?

Comment: @DouglasPettersson Use classes instead of IDs. Then you can use `$(this).closest(".edit_roomRow").find(".c-description")` to get the description field in the same form as the div they click on.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, thanks! Gonna see if that works out

Comment: @Barmar Should i put that and then .val();? Like: $(this).closest(".edit_roomRow").find(".c-description").val();

Comment: You should use it when assigning to the variables `id`, `description`, and `roomnumber`. In the callback function, you'll need to use a closure variable instead of `$(this)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539521/javascript-owner-of-this/24539572#24539572

Comment: @Barmar Yes.. but how do i find the value of each of those input fields with the line you sent? Or can i after that assign normal var xxx = $(".c-roomnumber").val()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reusing the same IDs in each DIV, you need to use classes instead. Then use DOM traversal functions to get the value of the input in the same DIV as the button the user clicked on.

This will require moving the `</div>` for the `.edit_roomRow` DIV to after the `.change-btn` DIV, so it's in the same DIV as the form.

PHP:

```
<?php
include('php/connect.php');

$chquery = "SELECT * FROM rooms";
$chresult = mysqli_query($conn, $chquery);

while($chrow = mysqli_fetch_array($chresult)){
    echo "<div class='edit_roomRow'>";
    echo "<h1> Rum " . $chrow['Roomnumber'] . "</h1>";
    echo "<form>";
    echo "Rumsnummer:<br> <input class='c-roomnumber' type='text' value = '" . $chrow['Roomnumber'] . "'><br>";
    echo "Beskrivning:<br> <input class='c-description' type='text' value = '" . $chrow['Description'] . "'>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<div class='btn btn-warning change-btn' data-value='". $chrow['ID'] . "' style='float: right; margin-top: 100px;'>Ändra</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<hr/>";
}

mysqli_free_result($chresult);

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

JS:

```
$(".change-btn").click(function(){
    var div = $(this).closest(".edit_roomRow");
    var id = $(this).attr("data-value");
    var description = div.find(".c-description").val();
    var roomnumber = div.find(".c-roomnumber").val();
    //Call to ajax
    $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url: "php/changepost.php",
        data:{ id: id, description: description, roomnumber: roomnumber },
        success: function(){
            div.find(".c-description").val("");
            div.find(".c-roomnumber").val("");
            //Reload specific div with rooms, avoid full page reload
            $(".changerooms").load(location.href + " .changerooms");
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Don't know why, but the values become 'undefined' and the post resets to no value at all in the DB

Comment: I misread your HTML. You have the `change-btn` outside the DIV for some reason.

Comment: Can you move it inside the `.edit_roomRow` DIV, or do I need to add another container to the HTML?

Comment: I can try moving it inside, i figured that was the issue. So the .closest cannot search outside a div?

Comment: Of course not. The definition of `.closest()` is to find the nearest enclosing element.

Comment: I updated my code and now have the <div> button inside the .edit_roomrow, still getting an undefined value, odd.

Comment: Not sure now what's wrong. Check the DOM in the browser's developer tools, make sure everything is nested correctly and the classes are set correctly.

Comment: Was a mixup in my div, tried changing to closest(form) just to try. Forgot to remove that. Now working perfectly. Thanks alot - Again, nice to have you guys here when newbies need help :)