# Node require executes code twice for mongoose Schemas

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am having trouble with require executing my code twice. Working on a standard Express app I build Mongoose Schemas, each in it's own files and export them.

```
//user.js
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
module.exports = User

//In other files
const User = require('../models/User')
```

Now I use this in two places in my application and get an error saying that

```
Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled.
```

So the code above is getting called twice as it is the only code right now creating a model. However I would expect Node to only execute it once since it is required in my code.

The really strange part is that checking out an earlier version from Git I get the same error and people working with me on this get the same error. So I have no more ideas where to look for solutions.

Comment: Try to write in the start of user.js `console.log(module.parent)`. This way you can see who called it.

Comment: This shouldn't happen: a file that has already been `require()`'ed will not be executed again.

Comment: @robertklep Yeah that is why I am so deeply confused right now.

Comment: @AmiramKorach that is cool to know. Now I know for certain that it's only called the two times I require it. Still wondering why the second require executes it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution now.

Turns out I required the module once as `models/user` and once as `model/User` which in the cache of require creates two separate modules.

There have been many discussion about this:

[one issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6000)

[another issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6829)

[old PR](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/pull/8145)

It seems that this is due to Windows resolving paths case insensitive while other systems resolve paths case sensitive and node therefore doing it sensitive.

And a new module of'cause gets executed. Simply requiring is both times spelled in lowercase solved the issue.

Comment: save yourself more frustrating problems with node development on windows. move to linux.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in "const" that you use to declare the variable "User".
Try to use "var" instead of .

```
//user.js
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
module.exports = User

//In other files
var User = require('../models/User')
```

P/S: This is link that clarify more about "const" and "var":

[Const in javascript? When to use it and is it necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/const-in-javascript-when-to-use-it-and-is-it-necessary)

Hope it helpful for you !

Comment: you should always prefer let over var.

Comment: Wouldn't think it should make a difference but tried it anyway, replacing all `const` with `var`. That didn't solve it.