# ES6 const usage in iteration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am reading Nodejs API, and I confused with iteration of buffer:

```
for (const b of buf10) {
  console.log(b)
}
```

`const` is used to declare constants, so why use `const` instead of `let`?

Comment: const simply means that the identifier wont be reassigned.

Comment: cant do `const variable = "something";` `while(true) {variable = "something else";}` when i know that i will not reassign the variable (eg when i create an instance of an object) i use const. Every other occasion let is used

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/const-in-javascript-when-to-use-it-and-is-it-necessary

Answer (score 6):

Because `b` *is* a constant in the loop scope. Remember that `let` and `const` have block scope in ES6. Every iteration does create a new variable which will stay constant in its scope.

Answer (score 2):

> const is used to declare constants, so why use const instead of let?

Because you can either use `var` `let` or `const` for declaration purpose however they behave differently.

In this case,

```
for (const b of buf10) {
  console.log(b)
}
```

Works because for each iteration you are getting a new const b and ending after the current iteration.

Concluding that if you know before hand that you are not going to modify the variable inside loop scope, you can go for it safely.

You'll see an error if you try to modify the `b` inside the loop.

Comment: Yeah! I use the closure test, `const` and `let` work different from `var`:
`let a = [];
for (const b of buf10) {
    a.push(function(){
        log(b);
    })
}`
`let b = [];
for (var c of buf10) {
    b.push(function(){
        log(c)
    })
}`

Comment: @Borkes Hope you saw the different values for b even inside closure where   others end up in same value

Comment: results are different of a and b, array of b has same value not a. @Suresh Atta