# Javascript - How change object properties without reassign them

Tags: javascript

The snippet below exposes the doubt

```
var foo = 'something'
var baz = 'other thing'

var obj = {
  prop1 : 'my prop',
  prop2 : foo,        //referencing external variable
  prop3 : baz         //referencing external variable
}

// here we get the expected obj to be printed
console.log(obj)

// now I change one of the initial variable
foo = 'changed'

// here we get the sabe print as the first, that is the ~problem~   
console.log(obj)
```

So, how to print 'changed' on prop2 without reassign  `obj.prop2 = foo`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you do

```
var obj = {
  prop1 : 'my prop',
  prop2 : foo,        //referencing external variable
  prop3 : baz         //referencing external variable
}
```

there is **no** ongoing link between `prop2` and the variable `foo` (or `prop3` and `baz`). All that happens is that the current **value** of `foo` is read, and stored in `prop2` (and the same for `baz` and `prop3`).

If you need `prop2` and `prop3` to remain linked to `foo` and `baz`, you could make them properties with *getters*. These are properties that trigger a function call when they're read (there are also *setters* which trigger a function call when the property is set):

```
var obj = {
  prop1 : 'my prop',
  get prop2() { return foo; },
  get prop3() { return baz; }
};
```

Accessing `obj.prop2` is a hidden function call. Since the function closes over `foo`, it returns `foo`'s current value.

Live Example:

```js
var foo = 'something';
var baz = 'other thing';

var obj = {
  prop1 : 'my prop',
  get prop2() { return foo; },
  get prop3() { return baz; }
};

console.log(obj);

foo = 'changed';

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 12):

Since JavaScript is pass by value instead of pass by reference you cannot override the previous value by assigning it directly to the variable.

You can though make an object of it, and change a property of the object like this:

```js
var foo = {value: 'something'}
var baz = 'other thing'

var obj = {
  prop1 : 'my prop',
  prop2 : foo,        //referencing external variable
  prop3 : baz         //referencing external variable
}

console.log(obj)

foo.value = 'changed'
 
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Excellent alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's happening:

1. The string `"changed"` is assigned to the variable `foo`
2. The value of `foo` is assigned to `obj.prop2`
3. Because this value is a string (as opposed to an array, object), `obj.prop2` simply gets the value. It does not get a *reference* to foo because these types of values (string, integer, boolean) can be stored in `obj` as is.

Now let's try the same thing with a different type:

```
var bloop = [1, 2, 3];
obj.prop4 = bloop;
console.log(obj.prop4); // [1, 2, 3]
bloop.push(4);
console.log(bloop); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(obj.prop4); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In this case, what we assign to `obj.prop4` is not a value like a string, integer, or boolean. Instead we are assigning a *reference* to an array stored in a different place in memory. `bloop` and `obj.prop4` both hold a reference to the same array in memory, so if the array is updated, both will update.

This actually works both ways:

```
obj.prop4.push(5);
console.log(obj.prop4); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(bloop); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So in summary if you are dealing with values like strings, ints, booleans you will not be able to change an object's properties the way you are describing. It will work only when the object property is a reference to an array, object, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're only getting the values of the variables, not linking the variables themselves:

```js
var foo = 'something'
var baz = 'other thing'

var obj = {
  prop1 : 'my prop',
  prop2 : foo,        //getting the value of external variable
  prop3 : baz         //getting the value of external variable
}

console.log(obj)

// change the value of prop2
obj.prop2 = 'changed'
  
console.log(obj)
```