# JSHint prevent redeclared global variable

Tags: javascript, jshint

I am using JSHint and I have a global variable (test) declared using the predef options. However in my code I can just override the global variable using

```
var test = 4;
```

Is there anyway to prevent this? I want to use my global variable without being able to override it in any way.

Comment: Use `const` instead of `var`.If your variable is a primitive, like number or string, it can't be overriden.

Comment: @HynekS  It can't be overridden directly, but could still be overridden in scope, which I think the op might be trying to prevent.  eg.  `const x = 1; { let x = 2; console.log(x); }` will still return 2.

Comment: I think you have to refer this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/const-in-javascript-when-to-use-it-and-is-it-necessary)!

Comment: @Keith Well, but it's not the same x! (It's its evil twin brother..)

Comment: @HynekS,

Yea Keith was right, I am aware how const works, but using const or var, my global variable test still gets overridden in the scope and I lose all previous data  :(

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood you. Well, as far as I know, you can't prevent overriding a variable in an enclosed scope (which is a function, try-catch-finally block or a literal block).