# Why const someValue = this.props.dispatch(someMethod()) is working fine on localhost but not in production?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I've one method called onChange and it's working as expected on localhost but not on production. Checkout the code below for better understanding:

```
onChange() {
   const someValue = this.props.dispatch(divideTenByFive()) // returns 2 on both local and prod
   console.log(someValue) // prints 2 on localhost and undefined on production
   console.log(this.props.dispatch(divideTenByFive())) // prints 2 on localhost and undefined on production
   return someValue; 
}
```

Is it related to Synchronous/Asynchronous programming? How to fix this for production?

Note: I can't share the actual business logic so I've written divideTenByFive() for better understanding. However, I've tried to provide max details but if you're looking for more info please comment below.

**Update:** I'm not using any middleware

Comment: are you using some middleware to return the value

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri No, I'm not using any middleware to return the value. It's simple try catch and if else going on inside divideTenByFive() which returns the expected value in production also.

Comment: Need a fully working code rather than 3 lines of code if you need help. Preferably on any open source website like GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try using var [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21237365/10634638) of const to declare the variable.

Once you’ve set it (to 2 on dev and to “undefined” in production) it cannot be changed.

This is because the value is not yet available, but const will prevent any modification later on.

Comment: I've tried using var instead of const but it's not working for this problem.

Comment: Can you also please try making it a global variable and pass it into your function..

Comment: You can make it a global variable by omitting var / const keywords.