# How to declare 'const' as an empty variable

Tags: javascript

I wonder if it is possible to declare 'const exch' as empty first since I need that variable to be global for a loop function?

The below does not seem to work?

```js
const exch;
exch = new ccxt.kortux ({ enableRateLimit: true })
```

Comment: You can't. `const` is a value that is set once declared, and it never can be reassigned thereafter.

Comment: [Const in javascript? When to use it and is it necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21237105/215552)

Comment: _The value of a constant cannot change through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared_

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn `const` values can change, they just can't get reassigned.

Comment: More to the point, unlike readonly in say C# or Java (which allow deferred assignment in certain contexts), const requires the expression at the declaration site - this is part of the syntax.

Comment: I see, then I understand. Then I need to declare the const as it is in one go. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Why not just write the usual `const exch = new ccxt.kortux ({ enableRateLimit: true })`? What do you mean by "*I need that variable to be global for a loop function*", can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
let exch;
exch = new ccxt.kortux ({ enableRateLimit: true })
```

or even better:

```
const exch = new ccxt.kortux ({ enableRateLimit: true })
```

`const` declarations are not able to be redefined, `let` declarations are.