# Does using const variable in angularjs factory makes positive impact on performance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In javascript we can change properties of constant object. So if I have some factory in AngularJs defined as below

```
      myApp.factory('sampleFactor', function() {
        var sampleFactoryVar =  {
         setFoobar: function(foo){
             //perform some operations
             return foo;
         },
         getFoobar:function(){
             //perform some operations
         }
       };
       return sampleFactoryVar;
     });
```

In this factory if I will be declaring `sampleFactoryVar` as `const` will it make any significant impact on performance ? 
Please consider `sampleFactoryVar` is holding lots of properties.

Comment: bro follow this link it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/21237365/7924858

Comment: https://medium.com/dailyjs/use-const-and-make-your-javascript-code-better-aac4f3786ca1

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't have any effect at all. You could in fact just omit the variable declaration and just `return` the object literal directly. However the factory is only called once, so performance hardly matters here anyway.