# How to clear all non-array intervals

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I have multiple timers on a single page which are being started by ajax updates. Every interval has its own name assigned to the username of players. I want to top all timers when the game ends:

This is how intervals are being created: `findNewPlayer()` is being called on some events in the game:

```
function findNewPlayer(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"check.php",
        success:function(data){newTimer(data)}
    })
}

function newTimer(username){
 var username=setInterval(function() {startTimer()}, 1000);
}

function startTimer(){
    //blah blah
}
```

Now I want to stop all timers and restart the game with current players. How can I use clearInterval on a series of usernames which are not generated in an array? I know if they were array I could do the following but I want to find a way to get collection of all timers with different names in a window.

```
for (i = 0; i < interValArray.length; i++) {
    clearInterval(interValArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain an array to hold the `ID` returned by the `setTimeout` call, then loop over the array on reset:

```
const timerIds = [];

function newTimer(username){
 timerIds.push(setInterval(function() {startTimer()}, 1000));
}
```

When you reset and start with new players, you need to clear the timers:

```
timerIds.forEach(clearInterval);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any reason that  you used const instead of var?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour as per the best practices it is recommended to always use `const` and make the array reference a constant so that later you don't accidentally overwrite it, now unless you really have a very urgent reason to change the reference later then you should go for `let/var `. 
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22939592/3888766) would also help you to know why. Although the array reference becomes a constant using `const` but the array itself is still pretty much mutable and additions/deletions can be made.