# Sort method altering constant value

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging

So, I was trying this LeetCode problem = https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

The solution that I wrote required me to sort an array, but I would need to return the indices related to the original array. Because of this, I created a constant to store the original and then search it later after I've found those indices.

My solution ended up not working because the sort method is altering that constant value. I don't know why this is happening, all I know is that the sort method alters the original array when called (that's why I needed to store it before sorting). I thought that if a created a constant it couldn't be altered afterward. That's why I think it's a bug or something

This is the code that I've been trying (I left the console.logs there for clarity)

To test you should use

```
nums = [3, 2, 4]
target = 6
```

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    var max = nums.length - 1;
    var min = 0;

    const nums2 = nums;
    console.log(nums2)
    var nums1 = nums.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
    console.log(nums2)
    while (min != max){

        if (nums1[min] + nums1[max] > target) {
            max -= 1;
        } else if (nums1[min] + nums1[max] < target) {
            min += 1;
        };        
        if (nums1[min] + nums1[max] == target) {
            return [nums2.indexOf(nums1[min]), nums2.indexOf(nums1[max])];        
        };
    };    
};
```

Comment: Also possibly relevant: [Const in javascript? When to use it and is it necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/const-in-javascript-when-to-use-it-and-is-it-necessary) and [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)

Comment: hey, thanks!! these are pretty helpful. I don't think it's actually a duplicate, because in that thread what it's being discussed is the matter of reassigning a value to a constant through declaration. In my example, I shouldn't be able to change the value of nums2 if it is a constant. I'm not saying that what I assigned to nums2 can't be changed, and that, I think, is the subject of the other thread. At least, I couldn't find it

Comment: You are not *reassigning* you constant - it's an array, so it's an object. Mutating an object is possible, even if it's a `const`. Your `nums` and `nums2` are *the same object`, not two different ones that happen to hold the same values.

Comment: You're *not* altering the const value, you're altering what it references.

Comment: To me it is weird that happens this way. It is the first time that I made any post or even logged in, but I should have just researched a little bit more, cause the links VLAZ posted could actually fix my problem... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here:

1. `const nums2 = nums;` does *not* copy the array, it just gives you a non-reassignable reference (e.g. you cannot assign a new value to `nums2` with `=`, but the contents of `num2` is up for grabs)
2. `nums.sort(...)` sorts *in place*, thus it does modify the original array
   (see [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)). Since `nums2` is a reference to `nums`, it shows those changes to `nums` in the second `console.log`

```js
nums = [3, 2, 4]
target = 6
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    var max = nums.length - 1;
    var min = 0;

    // force a copy of the array
    // note: this is a shallow copy
    const nums2 = nums.slice();
    console.log(nums2)
    var nums1 = nums.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
    console.log(nums2)
    while (min != max){

        if (nums1[min] + nums1[max] > target) {
            max -= 1;
        } else if (nums1[min] + nums1[max] < target) {
            min += 1;
        };        
        if (nums1[min] + nums1[max] == target) {
            return [nums2.indexOf(nums1[min]), nums2.indexOf(nums1[max])];        
        };
    };    
};

twoSum(nums, target);
```

Comment: This would probably work just fine. Thanks!!!

Comment: @RodrigoMallmann If this actually gives you an answer you find to be valuable, you can also mark it as answering your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry, I'm a total noob! hahaha. Now I think I've done it