# Node JS .shift() 'ing an array that was initialized by const

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used

```
const args = process.argv; args.shift(); args.shift()
```

to line up my command line arguments and ignore the first 2 words `node index.js`

My code works just fine but it gives me a bit of anxiety regarding `const` as a word in NodeJS.

`args` is not a constant if i'm allowed to change it. Does anybody know why it works the way it does?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Const in JavaScript: when to use it and is it necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/const-in-javascript-when-to-use-it-and-is-it-necessary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` doesn't make something immutable, it just means you can't re-assign it to a new value. You can add whatever you want to existing object and array consts. For immutability, you would want a 3rd party library.

Regarding using `args.shift();`, I would caution against it since it mutates the `args` array in place. Why not do something like `const myArgs = args.slice(2);` which returns a copy of the array minus the first two items?

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for, just going to leave it here to stew a bit. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let us take an example:

`const arr = ["a", "b", "c"]`

> arr will be assigned an address to an object created in the heap, which has keys 0, 1, 2 i.e indexes as a key.

As arrays are nothing but an object in js.

When you do shift operation on `const` arr, we are not changing the value of address assigned to variable `arr` in stack memory, we are just removing 0th key from the object at that address.

```
Stack memory       Heap Memory
|        |        | {         |
|        |        |   0 : "a" |
|        |        |   1 : "b" |
|        |        |   2 : "c" |
|arr = 8k|        |  }        |
----------        -------------

Here, 8k is the address of the object created in heap memory.
Which is assigned to variable arr in stack memory.
```

So, after doing a `shift` operation our `arr` changes to `["b", "c"]`

```
Stack memory       Heap Memory
|        |        | {         |
|        |        |           |
|        |        |   1 : "b" |
|        |        |   2 : "c" |
|arr = 8k|        |  }        |
----------        -------------

0th key from object in heap memory is removed.
```