# Getting the same result on JS

Tags: javascript

```
var luckyNumbers1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var luckyNumber1 = luckyNumbers1[Math.floor(Math.random () * 7)];

console.log ("Your winning numbers are " + luckyNumber1 + ", " +
luckyNumber1 + ", " + luckyNumber1 + "!");
```

Why do I get the same set of numbers? I noticed that if I do more luckyNumbers the sets will be different. But how come Javascript uses only 1 method to randomize the number of this variable?
e.g. :

```
" Your winning numbers are 1, 1, 1!"
" Your winning numbers are 5, 5, 5!"
```

thanks, Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

Because once the variable `luckyNumber1` is defined, it does not change afterwards no matter how many times it's referenced unless it gets overwritten (you never overwrite it in your code).

Answer (score 1):

Use a function.

```js
var luckyNumbers1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function luckyNumber1() {
  return luckyNumbers1[Math.floor(Math.random () * 7)]
  }

console.log ("Your winning numbers are " + luckyNumber1() + ", " +
luckyNumber1() + ", " + luckyNumber1() + "!");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var luckyNumbers1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var getLuckyNumber1 = () => luckyNumbers1[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];

console.log ("Your winning numbers are " + getLuckyNumber1() + ", " +
getLuckyNumber1() + ", " + getLuckyNumber1() + "!");
```

Because you are using the same variable, you are assigning a value to luckyNumber1 and you just keep reusing that without regenerating the random number. Having it in a function it will do it.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior for your code. You must understand that the value that you are assigning to `luckyNumber1` is evaluated just once, so the `Math.random()` part of your code run once.

You should put your code inside a function to make it be called multiple times.
Also you should use `const` and `let` instead of `var` (see [Const in JavaScript: when to use it and is it necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/const-in-javascript-when-to-use-it-and-is-it-necessary/21237365)).

The correct code should look like this:

```js
const luckyNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

const drawLuckyNumber = () => {
    return luckyNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random () * 7)];
}

console.log ("Your winning numbers are " + drawLuckyNumber() + ", " +
drawLuckyNumber() + ", " + drawLuckyNumber() + "!");
```

Comment: using the const keyword will let you only use 1 option to log in the console. Because it will remain constant the same.

Comment: That's not true. Run the snippet. The const here is used a) for the available numbers b) to store the function instead of putting it on global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's kinda tossing out different versions of the same answer. You need to be generating a new value each time instead of generating a value once and referencing it over and over. I'd do this with [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) to make the randomness simpler and more readable, but that's just a preference. All of the answers here work.

```js
var luckyNumbers1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
console.log ("Your winning numbers are " + rando(luckyNumbers1).value + ", " + rando(luckyNumbers1).value + ", " + rando(luckyNumbers1).value + "!");
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

If you want to use this code, don't forget to add the paste the `script` tag in the head of your html document.