# Are there any drawbacks on using this kind of JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following JavaScript code:

```
const myObject = {
   innerValue: 'test'
}

myObject.innerValue = 'I can still change this, this is not a constant';
```

If I run this code, the browser outputs no errors, I presume, because only the outer object `myObject` is a constant and its properties are not. But how valid is this JavaScript code? I mean, are there any negative drawbacks to writing something like this?

Comment: There is no problem writing like it since Javascript is a dynamic language.

Comment: Perhaps you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/const-in-javascript-when-to-use-it-and-is-it-necessary

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with this.  It's exactly as intended.  You haven't changed the value of `myObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you already understand that the variable `myObject` is const, but the object to which it refers is not.  That's very much by design for JavaScript.  Using `const` the way you did does *not* protect you from modifying the object.

You could use a property to protect the value of `innerValue`.

```js
const myObject = {};
Object.defineProperty(myObject, 'innerValue', {
  value: 'test',
  writable: false
});

console.log(myObject.innerValue);
myObject.innerValue = 'this is not an error but will not change the value';
console.log(myObject.innerValue);
```

Comment: `writable` defaults to `false` so there's no need to set it explicitly. You should mention in your answer that property defined by using `Object.defineProperty()` function is, by default,  not enumerable, not configurable and not writable.