# `setNum(() => num++)` not working, but `setNum(() => num + 1)`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am practicing React using Hooks and Context, working on a simple Quiz App. The score should increment to 1 when the answer is correct.

```
const { qa, questionNumber } = useContext(GlobalContext);
const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

const answerOnClick = (e) => {
  const correct = qa[questionNumber].correct_answer === e ? true : false;

  if (correct) {
    setScore(() => score++);
  }
};
```

But I'm getting this error on line `setScore(() => score++);`:

> TypeError: Assignment to constant variable

I also tried `if (correct) { score++; setScore(() => score); }` and `setScore(() => ++score)`, still not working.

**But when I try `setScore(() => score + 1);`, now it increments!**

I have learned that the [Increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment) is a valid JS operator. Aren't `score++` and `score + 1` equivalent? And why `score` treat as a constant variable? It is mutable, right? I'm still a novice developer. Can someone explain what's happening here? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Const in JavaScript: when to use it and is it necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/const-in-javascript-when-to-use-it-and-is-it-necessary)

Comment: Additional reading that could help: [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980) [When to use functional setState](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48209452/1218980)

Comment: I just recalled that `score++` is equivalent to `score += 1`, not `score + 1`, and `score` should not be reassigned. Thanks for the helpful links, @EmileBergeron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that `score` is defined as constant. This means that is should not be reassigned. When using `score++` you're reassigning it as follows `score = score + 1` but as a short hand. Your JavaScript interpreter does not like that you're reassigning a variable which you defined as being constant. Therefore you get the error.

The `useState` hook provides an update function (in your case `setScore`) which you should use to update the state. You're not directly changing the value of `score`. You're telling react to initialise `score` with a higher value on **next render**. Your components function is called again with a new declaration of `score`, this time with a higher value.  As you correctly pointed out `setScore(() => score + 1)` works, however, `setScore(score + 1)` should work too.

Answer (score 0):

You mutate the state when you do `score++`. You should not mutate the state in React because setNum is async.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

Comment: While true that we shouldn't mutate the state, it's not what OP is encountering. He's just trying to assign to a `const` value, which throws a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

`score++/++score` would mutate the state. The best way to update state based on previous state is this way:

```
setScore((prevScore) => prevScore + 1);
```