# How can these multiple assignments be simplified?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multiple-assignment

Can this code be simplified to a single assignment? The three variables are inputs I receive from the frontend. I’m using the `xss` module in Node.js.

```js
var clientname = xss(req.body.clientName, {
    whiteList: [],
    stripIgnoreTag: true,
    stripIgnoreTagBody: ['script']
});
var clientnumber = xss(req.body.clientNumber, {
    whiteList: [],
    stripIgnoreTag: true,
    stripIgnoreTagBody: ['script']
});
var clientaddress = xss(req.body.clientAddress, {
    whiteList: [],
    stripIgnoreTag: true,
    stripIgnoreTagBody: ['script']
});
```

Comment: Which Node.js version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

[Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods) are useful for this:

```js
const xssOptions = {
    whiteList: [],
    stripIgnoreTag: true,
    stripIgnoreTagBody: [
      "script"
    ]
  },
  [
    clientName,
    clientNumber,
    clientAddress
  ] = [
      "clientName",
      "clientNumber",
      "clientAddress"
    ].map((property) => xss(req.body[property], xssOptions));
```

The only thing that changes throughout your assignments is the property name after `req.body`, so pass that as an argument to an Array’s `map` call, mapping each of those property names to their respective `xss` call. Once the `xss` calls return, their return values are stored in an array in the same order, then destructured into three separate variables.

Alternatively, you could use an object grouping them all together:

```js
const xssOptions = {
    whiteList: [],
    stripIgnoreTag: true,
    stripIgnoreTagBody: [
      "script"
    ]
  },
  myXSSObjects = Object.fromEntries([
      "clientName",
      "clientNumber",
      "clientAddress"
    ].map((property) => [
      property,
      xss(req.body[property], xssOptions)
    ]));

console.log(myXSSObjects.clientName);
```

---

Additional considerations:

1. [Use `const` instead of `var`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21237105/4642212).
2. By convention, JavaScript identifiers use `camelCase`, not `alllowercase`.
3. Cache the object that is being used as the second argument to `xss` in another variable for reusability and efficiency.