# Javascript global scope with const vs var

Tags: javascript

```
var name = 'John';

console.log(this.name, document.name, window.name, name);

const meme = "Bruce";

console.log(this.meme, document.meme, window.meme, meme);
```

Output:

```
John undefined John John
undefined undefined undefined "Bruce"
```

Is global scope differently defined for var and const? I thought the only difference would be the const is immutable.

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75 + https://stackoverflow.com/a/40775470/2008111

Comment: One small thing: const is not immutable (for example you can do array.push()), but it’s not rewriteble (you can not reassign variables)

Comment: `const` does not work on older browsers (e.g. IE10), `var` works.

Comment: @caramba that article doesn't appear to have anything to do with OP's question

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  `window` scope and variables defined using `var` is different from the scope of variables declared using `const` and `let`.

See also [Is it possible to delete a variable declared using const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424019/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-variable-declared-using-const), [Why does .then() chained to Promise.resolve() allow const declaration to be reassigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380637/why-does-then-chained-to-promise-resolve-allow-const-declaration-to-be-reas)