# variables not accessible within function

Tags: javascript, function

I have some variables that are not included in the function but just outside of where they are created. I know I can pass them as parameters however I am looking for a more elegant method.

Code:

```
Tree.prototype.add = function(path){
var pathSplit = path.split('/');
//gets the length of the path
const pathLength = pathSplit.length;
//this compares the path to the nodes/directories
let compare = (currentNode, n) => {
    console.log(n);
    if(n == pathLength -1){
        console.log(pathLength);
        //create a new node with file name as data
        var nodeFile = new Node(pathSplit[n]);
        //adds the file name onto the the node
        currentNode.children.push(nodeFile);
        //sets the node parent to the currentNode
        nodeFile.parent = currentNode;
    }else{
        //console.log('THIS IS RUN');
        var newNode = () => this.traversalBF(currentNode, pathSplit[n]);
           //console.log(newNode);
           compare(newNode, n++);
       };

   };
   compare(this._root, 0);
   };
```

the variable `PathLength` is considered to be `0` inside the compare function. however it should be `3` when it is called:

```
tree.add('one/two/three');
```

Comment: also the code runs like 1000 times not sure why if there is any help on that, that would be nice

Comment: Not certain what you are trying to achieve? What is the issue with the code at Question?

Comment: The call has a missing quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your recursive call you pass the value of `n++`. Note that this passes the value of `n` *before* it is increased. So you get an infinite recursion-chain where the path length is never reached.

Instead do:

```
        compare(newNode, n+1);
```

Note: The value of `pathLength` is never 0. You log both `n` and `pathLength` at different locations in your code, and so you might have confused one for the other. It is `n` that is 0.

Comment: yes you absolutely correct I did get confused by the n and pathLength I realised that after.

Answer (score 0):

> PathLength is considered to be 0 inside the compare function. however
>   it should be 3 when it is called

`pathLength` is declared using `const`. The value of `pathLength` cannot be changed. See

- [Is it possible to delete a variable declared using const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424019/)
- [Why does .then() chained to Promise.resolve() allow const declaration to be reassigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380637/)

You can declare the variable using `let` and within the function change the value of the variable.